# How to parse through a JSON response starting with :{

Tags: java, arrays, json, api

How can I fetch the "year" value from the response. I know how to  fetch all the other attributes. I am having trouble in fecthing the attributes coming inside an object starting with  :{

```
{  
    "statusCode":"1001",
    "message":"Success",
    "response":{  
        "holidays":[  
            {  
            "holidayId":78,
            "year":2015,
            "date":"2015-01-01",
            "day":"Thrusday",
            "occasion":"New Year Day",
            },
           {  
            "holidayId":79,
            "year":2015,
            "date":"2015-01-15",
            "day":"Thrusday",
            "occasion":"Pongal/Sankranthi",
            },
           {  
            "holidayId":80,
            "year":2015,
            "date":"2015-01-26",
            "day":"Monday",
            "occasion":"Republic Day",
           }
       ],
       "year":0
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What did you write? What's the problem?

Comment: JSONObject MainjsonObject= new JSONObject(result);
    String code = MainjsonObject.getString("year");

Comment: There is no object starting with `:{` in the JSON in your question. The only `:` there are the ones that follow field names. So it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: under response I have to get the value of year. How to do it

Comment: there also seem to be extra comma's in the file,  (after the 'occasion' fields in the holiday arrays), that make it invalid JSON afaik?